# Validation not working on dynamic inputs - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, dynamic, onblur

I have written a simple validation function for a series of input tags.  These work fine first time round but when I re-write the parent div html using jQuery, the blur function no longer triggers.

Basically, the script will not allow the questionnaire to move forward to the next page unless all input fields validate.  Once all input fields do validate, I make a copy of the current "page" of the questionnaire and store it in a variable called previousPage - this allows me to rewrite the questionnaire if the user clicks back (along with the previously entered values).

Everything works - up until the point where a user changes an input on going "back" but then because the blur event is not triggering, the validation is not running and the form can be progressed despite being incomplete.

Here is my blur hook:

```
$("body").on('blur', 'input', function(){
    rules = '';
    rulesValues = '';
    lastInput = $(this).attr('id');
    if($(this).data('rules')){
        rules = $(this).data('rules').split(',');
    }

    if($(this).data('rules-values')){
        rulesValues = $(this).data('rules-values').split(',');
    }

    validateData = $(this).val();
    if(rules && rulesValues){
        $.each(rules, function(index, value) {
            validationResult = inputValidator(rules[index],rulesValues[index],validateData);
            if(validationResult !== "PASSED"){
                $('#'+lastInput+'').after('<div class="validationFail">'+validationResult+'</div>');
                $('#'+lastInput+'').addClass('emptyInput');
                incomplete = true;
            }else{
                incomplete = false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle which illustrates the problem:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nojobc3/1/)

Comment: Your blur function triggers, but dynamically added input's doesn't have `$(this).data('rules')` and `$(this).data('rules-values')`, so this `if(rules && rulesValues)` check will fail

Comment: Something like this you would like? http://jsfiddle.net/0nojobc3/3/

Comment: Ahhh I see what I did, I forgot to add the data attributes to the copy - thanks for the extra eyes :)

Comment: I wanted to upvote you for the help but I am new here and can't seem to find where to do it, sorry.

Comment: Have a nice day =) You will have vote ability for comments in future.